# Broadcasting N-dim array to (N+1)-dim array and summing on all but 1 dim

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, array-broadcasting

Assume you have a numpy array with shape (a,b,c) and a boolean mask of shape (a,b,c,d).
I would like to apply the mask to the array iterating over the last axis, sum the masked array along the first three axes, and obtain a list (or an array) of length/shape (d,).
I tried to do this with a list comprehension:

```
Result = [np.sum(Array[Mask[:,:,:,i]], axis=(0,1,2)) for i in range(d)]
```

It works, but it does not look very pythonic and it is a bit slow as well.
I also tried something like

```
Array = Array[:,:,:,np.newaxis]
Result = np.sum(Array[Mask], axis=(0,1,2))
```

but of course this doesn't work, since the dimension of the Mask along the last axis, d, is larger than the dimension of the last axis of the Array, 1.
Also, consider that each axis could have dimension of order 100 or 200, so repeating the Array d times along a new last axis using `np.repeat` would be really memory intensive, and I would like to avoid this.
Are there any other faster and more pythonic alternatives to the list comprehension?

Comment: A cheap way of doing the `repeat` is: `np.broadcast_to(arr[...,None], mask.shape)[mask]`.  But the result is 1d, loosing all the 'by row' information.  In general, the number of True values per row (last dimension) varies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The most straightforward way of broadcasting a N-dimensional array to a matching (N+1)-dimensional array is to use [`np.broadcast_to()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html):

```
import numpy as np


arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (2, 3))
mask = np.random.randint(0, 2, (2, 3, 4), dtype=bool)
b_arr = np.broadcast_to(arr[..., None], mask.shape)
print(mask.shape == b_arr.shape)
# True
```

However, as @hpaulj already pointed out, you cannot use `mask` for slicing `b_arr` without loosing the dimensions.

---

Given that you want to just sum the elements together and summing zeroes "does not hurt", you could simply multiply element-wise your array and your mask so as to keep the correct dimension but the elements that are `False` in the mask are irrelevant for the subsequent `sum` of the corresponding array elements:

```
result = np.sum(b_arr * mask, axis=tuple(range(mask.ndim - 1)))
```

or, since `*` will do the broadcasting automatically:

```
result = np.sum(arr[..., None] * mask, axis=tuple(range(mask.ndim - 1)))
```

without the need to use [`np.broadcast_to()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.broadcast_to.html) in the first place (but you still need to match the number of dimension, i.e. using `arr[..., None]` and not just `arr`).

---

As @PaulPanzer [already pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57983499/5218354), since you want to sum up over all but one dimensions, this can be further simplified using [`np.matmul()`/`@`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.matmul.html):

```
result2 = arr.ravel() @ mask.reshape(-1, mask.shape[-1])
print(np.all(result == result2))
# True
```

For fancier operations involving the summation, please have a look at [`np.einsum()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.einsum.html).

---

## EDIT

The catch with broadcasting is that it will create temporary arrays during the evaluation of your expressions.

With the number you seems to be dealing with, I simply cannot use the broadcasted arrays as I run into `MemoryError`, but time-wise the element-wise multiplication may still be a better approach than what you originally proposed.

Alternatively, if you are after speed, you could do this at a somewhat lower level with explicit looping in Cython or Numba.

Below you can find a couple of Numba-based solutions (working on `ravel()`-ed data):

- `_vector_matrix_product()`: does not use any temporary array
- `_vector_matrix_product_mp()`: some as above but using parallel execution
- `_vector_matrix_product_sum()`: uses `np.sum()` and parallel execution

```
import numpy as np
import numba as nb


@nb.jit(nopython=True)
def _vector_matrix_product(
        vect_arr,
        mat_arr,
        result_arr):
    rows, cols = mat_arr.shape
    if vect_arr.shape == result_arr.shape:
        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(cols):
                result_arr[i] += vect_arr[j] * mat_arr[i, j]
    else:
        for i in range(rows):
            for j in range(cols):            
                result_arr[j] += vect_arr[i] * mat_arr[i, j]


@nb.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def _vector_matrix_product_mp(
        vect_arr,
        mat_arr,
        result_arr):
    rows, cols = mat_arr.shape
    if vect_arr.shape == result_arr.shape:
        for i in nb.prange(rows):
            for j in nb.prange(cols):
                result_arr[i] += vect_arr[j] * mat_arr[i, j]
    else:
        for i in nb.prange(rows):
            for j in nb.prange(cols):        
                result_arr[j] += vect_arr[i] * mat_arr[i, j]


@nb.jit(nopython=True, parallel=True)
def _vector_matrix_product_sum(
        vect_arr,
        mat_arr,
        result_arr):
    rows, cols = mat_arr.shape
    if vect_arr.shape == result_arr.shape:
        for i in nb.prange(rows):
            result_arr[i] = np.sum(vect_arr * mat_arr[i, :])
    else:
        for j in nb.prange(cols):
            result_arr[j] = np.sum(vect_arr * mat_arr[:, j])


def vector_matrix_product(
        vect_arr,
        mat_arr,
        swap=False,
        dtype=None,
        mode=None):
    rows, cols = mat_arr.shape
    if not dtype:
        dtype = (vect_arr[0] * mat_arr[0, 0]).dtype
    if not swap:
        result_arr = np.zeros(cols, dtype=dtype)
    else:
        result_arr = np.zeros(rows, dtype=dtype)
    if mode == 'sum':
        _vector_matrix_product_sum(vect_arr, mat_arr, result_arr)
    elif mode == 'mp':
        _vector_matrix_product_mp(vect_arr, mat_arr, result_arr)
    else:
        _vector_matrix_product(vect_arr, mat_arr, result_arr)
    return result_arr


np.random.seed(0)
arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (2, 3, 4))
mask = np.random.randint(0, 2, (2, 3, 4, 5), dtype=bool)
target = arr.ravel() @ mask.reshape(-1, mask.shape[-1])
print(target)
# [820 723 861 486 408]
result1 = vector_matrix_product(arr.ravel(), mask.reshape(-1, mask.shape[-1]))
print(result1)
# [820 723 861 486 408]
result2 = vector_matrix_product(arr.ravel(), mask.reshape(-1, mask.shape[-1]), mode='mp')
print(result2)
# [820 723 861 486 408]
result3 = vector_matrix_product(arr.ravel(), mask.reshape(-1, mask.shape[-1]), mode='sum')
print(result3)
# [820 723 861 486 408]
```

with improved timing over any `list`-comprehension-based solutions:

```
arr = np.random.randint(0, 100, (256, 256, 256))
mask = np.random.randint(0, 2, (256, 256, 256, 128), dtype=bool)


%timeit np.sum(arr[..., None] * mask, axis=tuple(range(mask.ndim - 1)))
# MemoryError

%timeit arr.ravel() @ mask.reshape(-1, mask.shape[-1])
# MemoryError

%timeit np.array([np.sum(arr * mask[..., i], axis=tuple(range(mask.ndim - 1))) for i in range(mask.shape[-1])])
# 24.1 s ± 105 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit np.array([np.sum(arr[mask[..., i]]) for i in range(mask.shape[-1])])
# 46 s ± 119 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit vector_matrix_product(arr.ravel(), mask.reshape(-1, mask.shape[-1]))
# 408 ms ± 2.12 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit vector_matrix_product(arr.ravel(), mask.reshape(-1, mask.shape[-1]), mode='mp')
# 1.63 s ± 3.58 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)

%timeit vector_matrix_product(arr.ravel(), mask.reshape(-1, mask.shape[-1]), mode='sum')
# 7.17 s ± 258 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

As expected, the JIT accelerated version is the fastest, and enforcing parallelism on the code does not result in improved speed-ups.
Note also that the approach with element-wise multiplication is faster than slicing (approx. twice as fast for these benchmarks).

---

## EDIT 2

Following @max9111 suggestion, looping first by rows and then by cols cause the most time-consuming loop to run on contiguous data, resulting in significant speed-up.
Without this trick, `_vector_matrix_product_sum()` and `_vector_matrix_product_mp()` would run at essentially the same speed.

Comment: These are all pretty great ideas and all of them work; however with the sizes of  arrays I'm working with (generally I have a=b=c=256 and d =128) I get either a large memory consumption or, when I solve for that, these solutions appear to be slower than the list comprehension. Is this normal? Or am I missing something?

Comment: @Quasark see edits. Basically, yes, broadcasting is memory inefficient and you need workarounds to gain some speed. In general, this operation will take time with the numbers you have (`mask` alone has 2 billion entries).

Comment: The loop ordering is suboptimal in your code. If you exchange the loop order you can get a large speedup  in _vector_matrix_product. In my case it was from 15.3s down to 193ms. The parallelized version isn't necessary because it runs slower than the single threaded version with this changes

Comment: @max9111 good catch! I updated my answer to reflect your suggestions.

Comment: @Quasark see latest updates for significant speed-ups while being on the memory efficient side.

Answer (score 1):

How about

```
Array.reshape(-1)@Mask.reshape(-1,d)
```

Since you are summing over the first three axes anyway you may as well merge them after which it is easy to see that the operation can be written as matrix-vector product

Example:

```
a,b,c,d = 4,5,6,7
Mask = np.random.randint(0,2,(a,b,c,d),bool)
Array = np.random.randint(0,10,(a,b,c))
[np.sum(Array[Mask[:,:,:,i]]) for i in range(d)]
# [310, 237, 253, 261, 229, 268, 184]    
Array.reshape(-1)@Mask.reshape(-1,d)
# array([310, 237, 253, 261, 229, 268, 184])
```